# OpenPyxl - inserting formula to cell error

Tags: python, excel, libreoffice

I use libre office to create test xlsx file. I pot only couple of digit to make a test. I then use python to sum two cells A2:B2
I save it and open xlsx file and I found that save was sucessful however cell show me #Nameerror - I check it and it show sum (small letters) when I change them to upper case in xlsx file the formula works. But my python file do not change it even if I used .upper command in py file. Can Anybody tell me what I doing wrong. To explain I use polish language in xlsx file so "SUM" is "SUMA".

````
import openpyxl


wb=openpyxl.load_workbook('test1.xlsx',data_only=True)
ws=wb['Arkusz1']

def formula():

    ws["C2"].value = "=SUMA(A2:B2)".upper()
    wb.save('test2.xlsx')

formula()
```[![File with inserted  by python - not working][1]][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/sSYij.jpg
````

Comment: If you use `=SUM(A2:B2)` instead of `=SUMA(A2:B2)` Maybe this work perfectly.

Comment: You can appreciate me by upvoting my other helpful post Thank you 

Answer (score 0):

Confirmed `ws["C2"] = "=SUM(A2:B2)"` works using Display Language: English. I don't know how formula names are affected by different languages.